# customized version of eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I currently have the android sdk running with eclipse. It happens to be that I also want to download stanford's customized version of eclipse in order to learn some other stuff. Will there be a problem downloading and installing this customized version if I already another version of eclipse installed on my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope! Just make sure you install them to different locations and (potentially) use different workspaces.  Eclipse is totally self-contained in the eclipse directory (or where ever you install it).